Can you help me using a Salesforce sample formula to get business hours between two date/time fields please?
I've been following this Salesforce documentation but it's not working.
I have a TimeLeft formula field that needs to calculate business hours between two dates. I mean, from NOW() to the due date field (Due_Date__c).
I have a formula to first check if the field is populated, or if it's still valid (if there is no data, or if we're past the due date, I'll just leave it null), then I check the country (there are 2 options:  countryA has 11 hours in a work day, and countryB has 12).
In this formula I found, I replaced 8 with the number of work hours; and I edited the starting time (16:00:00 I changed it to 12:00:00 for countryA; and 15:00:00 for countryB, following the GMT time thing)
Also, is there any way I can get not only the remaining business hours, but also minutes? in this format: "9:34"
(If this can't be done with a formula field, and only with code, can you please guide me a little bit?)
This is my attempt, any help will be greatly appreciated
IF(OR((Due_Date__c < NOW()),(ISNULL(Due_Date__c))),NULL, IF(TEXT(Account__r.Country__c) = 'countryA',ROUND( 11 * (
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( Due_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 12:00:00') ) / 7) +
    MIN(5, 
     FLOOR ( MOD ( Due_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 12:00:00'), 7) / 1) +
     MIN( 1, 24 / 11 * ( MOD( Due_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 12:00:00' ), 1 ) ) )
    ) 
   )
 -
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( NOW() - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 12:00:00') ) / 7) +
     MIN( 5,
      FLOOR( MOD( NOW() - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 12:00:00'), 7) / 1) +
      MIN( 1, 24 / 11 * ( MOD( NOW() - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 12:00:00' ), 1) ) )
    )
   ) 
  ), 
2 ) ,ROUND( 12 * (
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( Due_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 15:00:00') ) / 7) +
    MIN(5, 
     FLOOR ( MOD ( Due_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 15:00:00'), 7) / 1) +
     MIN( 1, 24 / 12 * ( MOD( Due_Date__c - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 15:00:00' ), 1 ) ) )
    ) 
   )
 -
   ( 5 * FLOOR( ( NOW() - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 15:00:00') ) / 7) +
     MIN( 5,
      FLOOR( MOD( NOW() - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 15:00:00'), 7) / 1) +
      MIN( 1, 24 / 12 * ( MOD( NOW() - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 15:00:00' ), 1) ) )
    )
   ) 
  ), 
2 ) ) )


